# Arithmetic in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, math, arithmetic-expressions, integer-arithmetic

I'm making a game, and I have a `Health` variable to track how much health the player has as they go through the game. At one point, the player cuts their lip on a can (Uneventful, I know), and lose 2 HP. I'm trying to use Arithmetic to subtract 2 HP from the 'Health' variable (Which is still at 100 at that point), and then show how much health they have left, yet it still shows 100 HP after I tried to remove 2 HP. Am I doing it right?

```
:Beans
call :colorEcho 7 "You decide you're going to have Canned Beans for     breakfast. Yum. You grab a knife from the kitchen counter and work the top off. You eat the beans straight from the can. Ouch! You cut your lip! It starts to    bleed."
Echo .
set /a "_Health=_Health-2"
Echo.
call :colorEcho C "# ALERT; You have lost 2 Health Points! You are now at %Health% HP!"
Echo.
pause
exit
```

What happens:

[image: what happens]

Comment: Did you try without the `"`s?

Comment: I guess this code fragment is in a block within parentheses `()`; if I'm right, you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), or you write `set /A _Health-=2`...

Comment: @i_am_jorf Yes, I tried without the `"`s, but I get the same result.

Comment: @aschipfl This block is not within parentheses, but I tried `set /a _Health-=2, but it still did not work.

Comment: If you want to take a look at the full code, i've uploaded it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/nRMV8Mvc

Comment: Why are you expanding `%Health%` when your variable is named `_Health`? Note -  you can simplify to `set /a _Health-=2`

Comment: @dbenham Ah, thank you so much for pointing that out! I had got the command from a different website, and it was using an example where `_` was included, so I had gotten confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out the answer thanks to @dbenham. Thank you!

I had messed up the variable, and as dbenham pointed out, I was expanding `%Health%` when I was using `_Health` in `set /a _Health-=2`. I changed it to just `set /a Health-=2`, and everything seems to be working fine now.